# How to check if AttachedFlyout is Open

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

What I have is this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" />
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</Grid>
```

I might be missing something because I am really surprised that there is no inbuilt property or a way that checks if the `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout` of a control is Open or not.

Is there some straight forward way like below mentioned code to achieve this?

```
if(MenuFlyout.GetAttachedFlyout(MyGrid).IsOpen)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no property like `IsOpen` for the `MenuFlyout`. Don't ask me why!

It is a little bit ugly, but you can achieve the check like this:

```
bool isMenuOpened;
MenuFlyout.GetAttachedFlyout(MyGrid).Opened += (sender, e) => isMenuOpened = true;
MenuFlyout.GetAttachedFlyout(MyGrid).Closed += (sender, e) => isMenuOpened = false;
```